# Equivalent of "textAnchor" for the g tag

Tags: svg

Is there an attribute to center an svg group tag inside of another svg tag (say g or svg)? I want this to be automatic without having to specify widths/heights just like "textAnchor".

Comment: you can put the group in the <defs> and use the group with `<use>`. The use can take a x and y attributes so that you can change it's position. In order to center the use element insife another group you will need the bounding box of both groups.Use the `getBBox()` method to get the bounding box

Comment: Given that a <g> tag is always the size of its contents, that makes the <g> tag contents automatically centred, no?